# Need help to define existing web app vulnerability

Tags: vulnerability, owasp-top-ten

I found vulnerability in a web app where I could manipulate URL parameters, i.e. take **host/friends.php** and then change it to **host/friends.php?view=username** and as a result see the users friends and subscriptions. Normally this view function is not provided by the web app's interface.

Now I would like to define this vulnerability using OWASP top 10 list, but I'm not too sure whether it is definition A5 or A7 or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you've provided it sounds like your issue would fit in to OWASP 2013 Top 10 under "[A7 - Missing Function Level Access Control](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A7-Missing_Function_Level_Access_Control)" as the application should apply an access control to restrict who can see that information but appears to be failing to do so.